# file_get_contents via facebook graph api returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the following code to get the number of facebook comments for a particular URL.

```
function get_facebook_comments_number() {
    $filecontent = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . $url);
    $json = json_decode($filecontent);
    $count = $json->$url->comments;
    if ($count == 0 || !isset($count)) {
        $count = 0;
    }
    return $count;
}
```

Sometimes it works, but than suddenly it stops working with the following error:

```
Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

On the server side everything should work fine. If I use a different URL (e.G. http://www.google.com) it works flawlessly. So it seems as I am reaching some limit of the facebook graph API. If I type the same URL in my browser it returns no error.

Anybody knows how to resolve this? Do I have to pass some kind of auth-code?

Comment: Yeah, that is likely an issue of rate limiting. You can try and use an access token in your request – but this is not guaranteed to help, if you are just making too many request. Are you making this API call on every load of your page? If so, consider implementing a cache.

Comment: The exact error reason is likely mentioned in the response body - to get that returned as well when using `file_get_contents`, you need to pass in a context that sets the option to return the body even on HTTP errors.

Comment: @CBroe I have added an access token and now it seems to work. Anyway I am doing these request on every pageload so it would probabbly a good idea to cache this. Do you have any ressource where I can learn how to do this? I expect to write it into the database with some timestamp and if the timestamp is older than two hours I will check again?